# Some questions about altering new Tokens from a non developer (ELI5 Please).

Tags: tokens

I am not a developer and have a basic understanding of Ethereum. I apologize in advance if these questions really seem strange and silly but don't have anyone to ask these questions - I tried searching but didn't find similar questions.

So if anyone can answer the questions that I have, I would really appreciate it:

1- Can an app be programmed such that it creates a new token every week or every month - so if it issues Token A and Token B on launch - say after a few weeks, I want to issue Token C on app - can an app do that?

Can the app's code be updated to launch as many different tokens I want?

So suppose the app launches with Coin A and Coin B - both coins have a fixed total number each - can the app's code be updated to create a new Coin C and then a new Coin D and then a new Coin E (all of them with fixed supply in existence) - and so on - can the app developer create as many different type of coins he wants to exist for his app?

I have read around that a person can increase the total supply of coins in existence, but I am not sure about whether a completely different coin can be introduced in the app.

2- If an app has Tokens A and B and C - and users are transferring the tokens between each other - is there some gas required by Ethereum Blockchain to handle those transactions or is there some way that those tokens can be moved around and app only pays gas for other functions and not every transaction.

Basically will the app developer need to cover the gas costs if some user is just sending around a few of Token A between various wallets that they own? Is there some way to tackle that?

Can the app somehow remove only Token A from its custom issued wallets to users and just keep Tokens B and C in the system? Or freeze all Token A's so that they cannot be moved around and only Tokens B and C can be moved around etc.

3 - So let's say an app has coin A and then coin A1 and then coin A2 - can only the app creator and developer create new coins or can the community create another coin say A2 and it's hard to tell which A2 coin is the original one.

4- Is there a way to serialize tokens - add some number of identification to each individual token - so if an app wants - it can tell which wallet has Token # 345 of Token A

Thanks.

Comment: I see this is your first question. May I suggest that you would probably get better answers, plus it would make finding specific questions and answers by others easier if you broke your questions into more focused single questions. One post == one question == one answer makes finding stuff easier, I think.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can have as many tokens as you want, and create them on demand. You can create a token factory contract, and use it to deploy contract for new tokens.
2. a. No, each user has to pay for its own transactions. Currently the user that initiates a transaction has to pay for the gas, a contract cannot pay for it. But you can make the contract refund users for the transaction const.

   b. Yes, you can lock all transactions for a token without affecting other tokens. If a token support ERC20 you have to block the operations `transfer` and `transferFrom`.
3. You can restrict your contracts to only accept tokens that you have created.
4. I'm not aware of any token with such property. But I'd not rule it as impossible, I'd say it is subject to research. For example there is a contract that can store ether and issue 'checks' for a third party to redeem for ether, and each of them have a unique id.